# JavaFX Button spams MouseExit and MouseEntered

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent

I'm trying to make a button disable when the mouse enters the node and enable it again when the mouse leaves it. The button responds to MouseEvent.ANY and the handle method gets the event type and handles it accordingly.
The println shows a constant stream of this even though I don't move the cursor:

MOUSE_EXITED
MOUSE_EXITED_TARGET
MOUSE_ENTERED
MOUSE_ENTERED_TARGET
MOUSE_EXITED
MOUSE_EXITED_TARGET
MOUSE_ENTERED
MOUSE_ENTERED_TARGET
MOUSE_EXITED
MOUSE_EXITED_TARG

This makes the button flicker on and off.

```
public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
        System.out.println(me.getEventType());
        if(me.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED_TARGET || me.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED) {
            nejButton.setDisable(true);
        }
        else if((me.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED) || (me.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED_TARGET) )nejButton.setDisable(false);
    }
```

Comment: might be a bug or something wrong in your setup - [mcve] please :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like disabling a `Node` means the mouse is no longer considered to be within its bounds. It may be a bit of a stretch, but I believe this is documented by the [`Node#disabled`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#disabledProperty) property:

> Indicates whether or not this `Node` is disabled. A `Node` will become disabled if `disable` is set to `true` on either itself or one of its ancestors in the scene graph.
>
> A disabled `Node` should render itself differently to indicate its disabled state to the user. Such disabled rendering is dependent on the implementation of the `Node`. The shape classes contained in `javafx.scene.shape` do not implement such rendering by default, therefore applications using shapes for handling input must implement appropriate disabled rendering themselves. The user-interface controls defined in `javafx.scene.control` will implement disabled-sensitive rendering, however.
>
> **A disabled `Node` does not receive mouse or key events.** [emphasis added]

What happens, I believe, is that when you disable the `Node` the mouse "exits" because said `Node` is no longer eligible to receive mouse events. This happens regardless of if you move your mouse or not. Then your code reacts to the mouse "exiting" and you enable the `Node`. However, since the now enabled `Node` is again eligible to receive mouse events, and the fact that you kept your mouse in the same place, the mouse "enters" the `Node` again. Your code then reacts to the mouse "entering" the `Node` and disables the it again—causing a never-ending loop.

I suspect there's no way to work around this behavior<sup>1</sup>.

That being said, I find the desired goal strange. What are you trying to tell the user by having the `Button` disabled only when the mouse hovers over it? It seems that would convey, "*Come click this button... just kidding!*". That doesn't seem like a pleasant user experience.

---

<sup>1. Since a disabled node does not receive mouse events one could argue this behavior is a bug. However, stopping this loop from occurring won't help your case; moving the mouse out of your button won't fire a mouse-exited event, regardless of if there's a "disabled while hovering" mouse-exited event fired or not. I also am inclined to believe this behavior is *not* a bug.</sup>

Comment: Interesting. That sound like a reasonable explanation! Thanks! And yeah it's just a bit of a troll program it's nothing serious.